# Ensure two items are siblings in JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, siblings

Given the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

the following is false:

```
($('#a').parent() == $('#b').parent()); //=> false
```

even though:

```
$('#a').parent().children('#b').length; //=> 1
```

Could anyone explain why? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% on exactly why it doesn't work, but I believe it is because the elements are wrapped in jQuery objects which are inherently different per element.

As a workaround, you can compare the native DOM object, like this:

```
($('#a').parent()[0] == $('#b').parent()[0]); // true
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Xazrv/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Because of the same reason that `$('#a) == $('#a')` is `false`

Each time jQuery builts a set of elements, it returns a *new* object (even if the jQuery object wraps the same elements as another). In JavaScript, the *only* time an object is equal to another, is if it's exactly the same object;

```
var a = {
    foo: 1
};
var b = {
    foo: 1
};

(a == b) // false;
```

To fix this, you can either compare the DOM objects directly (either by using [`.get(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/get) or using the jQuery object like an array (`[i]`)), or you get use the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) method;

```
if ($('.foo').get(i) == $('.bar').get(i));
if ($('.foo')[0] == $('.bar')[0]);
if ($('.foo').is($('.bar')); // or even...
if ($('.foo').is('.bar'));
```

Comment: `$('.foo').is('.bar')` should suffice.